# Custom Grails plugin dependency

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

I have a custom grails plugin I m trying to develop and set this

```
def dependsOn = [dataSource: "1.0"]
```

in the Plugin script.

Now, my custom plugin loads just fine but I dont see tomcat installed in my application. How does one install a dependency plugin (prompt the user to say yes/no)? Is this even possible?

Comment: I think the Tomcat plugin is a "development" time plugin. I would not expect to see tomcat in my "war".

Comment: Sorry, maybe I used a bad example .. Lets say its dataSource:1.0

Answer (score 1):

Once your plugin is published, this should work. Try:

```
grails install-plugin nimble
```

You will see that both Nimble and Shiro are installed (Nimble depends on Shiro).

Comment: Well what if the plugin is not published?

Comment: It will work if you use install-plugin with a file or a URL. It won't work if you include the plugin via the in-place mechanism (`grails.plugin.location...` in BuildConfig.groovy).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Grails version you're using, but Grails 1.2 has much improved dependency management for plugins and apps; see this [post by Graeme Rocher](http://graemerocher.blogspot.com/2009/09/grails-dependency-resolution-done-right.html) for details.